# DataTypes XSD two WSDL files - Types 'X' and X' both use the XML type name, 'X', from namespace ''

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, serialization

I received two WSDL + XSD files and one xsd datatypes file from an organisation.
Both WSDL file are imported/ used as (two) service reference(s).

As soon as I serialize an object I am receiving the below exception:
Types 'X' and X' both use the XML type name, 'X', from namespace Y.

The problem is; both WSDL files are using the same object/class of the xsd file.
How to solve this problem, without modifying the WSDL files? Do I need to combine the WSDL files? Or is it possible to point both WSDL files to some shared datatypes file?

if you need more information/ details, please write a comment.

Thank you in advance.

*I am using C#, Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Use different namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new WSDL file which imports both (received) WSDL files.

*Note: The WSDL and XSD files need to be in the same directory.*

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <import location="LOCATION WSDL1"/>
    <import location="LOCATION WSDL2"/>
</definitions>
```